# Remove vertical space between text and border

Tags: html, css

I want to reduce the space between my number and its top and bottom borders.

[image]

As you can see my number fills the whole width but is too short to fill height.

How can I change that?

```
#number {
   position: absolute;
   color: white;
   font-size: 14vmin;
   border: 5px solid white;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to play with the `line-height` value. Because of the size of the font, the `line-height` is likely adding a lot of space on top and bottom. Try this:

```
#number {
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    font-size: 14vmin;
    border: 5px solid white;
    line-height: 1; /* NEW; also try .8, .9, 1.1, 1.2, etc. */
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thx for quick help.